# How do I resolve "Packages is not defined" in WSO2 Carbon 4.0.3 with Application Server Features?

Tags: rhino, wso2

I am attempting to upgrade from WSO2 Carbon 3.0.0 to Carbon 4.0.3.  Using Carbon 3.0.0, after installing the necessary features, I'm able to write JavaScript Mashup services that can call external Java libraries--and since WSO2 carbon uses Rhino, I'm able to use importPackage.  I have not been able to get the same functionality working on Carbon 4.0.3.

The procedure I've followed is:

1. Download and unzip WSO2 Carbon 4.0.3
2. Start Carbon
3. Navigate to the "Feature Management" page
4. Add the 4.0.3 Carbon p2 repository (http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.0.3/)
5. Search for and install the "Application Server" feature
6. Restart Carbon
7. Deploy my test Mashup service
8. Execute the echo operation of my test Mashup service using the "tryit" tool.

My test Mashup service (TestMashup.js):

```
this.serviceName = "TestMashup";

echo.inputTypes = "#raw";
echo.outputType = "#raw";
function echo(parameter) {
    var javaDate = new Packages.java.util.Date();
    var response = "<echo><value>" + parameter.toXMLString() + "</value><timestamp>" + javaDate.getTime() + "</timestamp></echo>";

    return new XML(response);
}
```

I've installed this Mashup service to CARBON_HOME/repository/deployment/server/jsservices/admin/

When I run this operation on Carbon 3.0.0, I get the following response:

```
<echo>
  <value>
    <r>test</r>
  </value>
  <timestamp>1360699125311</timestamp>
</echo>
```

When I attempt to run this operation on Carbon 4.0.3, I get the following stack-trace:

```
[2013-02-12 14:46:32,511] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine} -  org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "Packages" is not defined.(//C:\WSO2CA~1\WSO2CA~1.3\bin\..\repository\deployment\server\jsservices\admin\TestMashup.js#6)
[2013-02-12 14:46:32,512] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine} -  org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "Packages" is not defined. (//C:\WSO2CA~1\WSO2CA~1.3\bin\..\repository\deployment\server\jsservices\admin\TestMashup.js#6)
[2013-02-12 14:46:32,512] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver} -  org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "Packages" is not defined. (//C:\WSO2CA~1\WSO2CA~1.3\bin\..\repository\deployment\server\jsservices\admin\TestMashup.js#6)
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "Packages" is not defined.(//C:\WSO2CA~1\WSO2CA~1.3\bin\..\repository\deployment\server\jsservices\admin\TestMashup.js#6)
        at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mashup.javascript.messagereceiver.JavaScriptEngine.call(JavaScriptEngine.java:176)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mashup.javascript.messagereceiver.JavaScriptEngine.call(JavaScriptEngine.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mashup.javascript.messagereceiver.JavaScriptReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(JavaScriptReceiver.java:185)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.FilterServletAdaptor$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterServletAdaptor.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mashup.jsservices.custom.ui.CustomUIServletFilter.doFilter(CustomUIServletFilter.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.FilterServletAdaptor.service(FilterServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:172)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "Packages" is not defined. (//C:\WSO2CA~1\WSO2CA~1.3\bin\..\repository\deployment\server\jsservices\admin\TestMashup.js#6)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execFunc(RhinoEngine.java:383)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.call(RhinoEngine.java:251)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mashup.javascript.messagereceiver.JavaScriptEngine.call(JavaScriptEngine.java:169)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "Packages" is not defined. (//C:\WSO2CA~1\WSO2CA~1.3\bin\..\repository\deployment\server\jsservices\admin\TestMashup.js#6)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execFunc(RhinoEngine.java:401)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execFunc(RhinoEngine.java:380)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "Packages" is not defined. (//C:\WSO2CA~1\WSO2CA~1.3\bin\..\repository\deployment\server\jsservices\admin\TestMashup.js#6)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3557)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3535)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:3620)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.name(ScriptRuntime.java:1652)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.c0._c1(//C:\WSO2CA~1\WSO2CA~1.3\bin\..\repository\deployment\server\jsservices\admin\TestMashup.js:6)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.c0.call(//C:\WSO2CA~1\WSO2CA~1.3\bin\..\repository\deployment\server\jsservices\admin\TestMashup.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:401)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3003)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.c0.call(//C:\WSO2CA~1\WSO2CA~1.3\bin\..\repository\deployment\server\jsservices\admin\TestMashup.js)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execFunc(RhinoEngine.java:398)
        ... 43 more
```

How do I fix this so that I can continue using Java libraries from my JavaScript Mashup services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that allowed this feature to work has been disabled.

I spent some time looking through the carbon SVN repository and discovered that the `message-receiver` mashup component was modified in such a way that prevents JavaScript Mashup services from being created with an `ImporterTopLevel` context.  This is directly visible in `org.wso2.carbon.mashup.javascript.messagereceiver.JavaScriptEngine`, where previous versions extend `ImporterTopLevel` but newer versions do not.  For future reference, this change was committed against revision 129254.

I've been able to merge the `ImporterTopLevel` code from 3.2.2 into the 4.0.3 version of `messagereceiver` to work around the problem.

Answer (score -1):

When you install required features to Carbon server, see whether there are any errors printed in the console. There may be some dependency issues. And after you install the features, start the WSO2 AS with command `./wso2server.sh -DosgiConsole` and using `ss` command and `comp` command see whether there are any unresolved OSGi dependencies. If there are any, try putting the required bundles into repository/components/dropins and restarting the server.

And also I am not sure whether only installing the Application Server feature will enable your  Mashup requirements. Therefore in that repository see whether there are any Mashup Server related features available. If so install them as well. It seems in your server, host object "Packages", has some problem.

When you fail to install some features due to dependency issues you can try putting required bundles in dropins directory. And if that also fails you may have to checkout the code relevant to that component and backport it to your server version.

Comment: SS shows all modules as INSTALLED, ACTIVE, or RESOLVED. Is there something specific I'm looking for?  I don't actually see any features that identity "Mashup Server"; it's my understanding that the Mashup Server is built into the Application Server.  What should I install to get this functionality?

Comment: See the OSGi documents in web for the OSGi commands. Using diag [id_showed_in_ss_command] you can explore whether there are any problems with the each item shown in ss command. If there is no feature similar to Mashup Server then see whether there are any features has names like Host Object. AFAIK Mashup Server is packed with Application Server only after the Mashup Server was abandoned. Earlier there was a separate Server called Mashup Server.

Comment: Maninda - can you at least confirm that this works for you? Or is supposed to work still???

Comment: It wont work - see Josh's comments above. In an effort to support Jaggery/Rhino engine instead of straight Rhino, ws02 have broken the ability to import jar files or native java into their JS service engine. Breaking things is not good when you call yourselves and Enterprise engine.